# Gmail API Send email with Attachment unavailable import class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I coded automation testing using selenide framework and need send the test report via email at the end of testing execution.

I have tried **sendgrid** service but it cannot send attachment. Sometimes can send email with attachment and sometimes cannot send email with attachment.

Then, I decided to give Gmail API a try but **some classes are not resolvable**. Below is the code:

```
public class EmailManager {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Buletin TV3";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "./credentials.json";

private static final String FROMEMAILAddress = "qa-automation@revmedia.my";
private static final String TOEMAILAddress = "qa-automation@revmedia.my";

public EmailManager() {
}

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = EmailManager.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    //returns an authorized Credential object.
    return credential;
}

public synchronized void sendEmail() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, MessagingException {
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();


    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
            .createScoped(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE);
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

    // Create the gmail API client
    Gmail gmailService = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    // Create the email content
    String messageSubject = "Buletv3 Test Report";
    String bodyText = "Dear Stakeholder, Please find the test report from attachment";

    // Encode as MIME message
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROMEMAILAddress));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(TOEMAILAddress));
    email.setSubject(messageSubject);

    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    mimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain");
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
    mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    mimeBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    email.setContent(multipart);

    // Encode and wrap the MIME message into a gmail message
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(buffer);
    byte[] rawMessageBytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(rawMessageBytes);
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

    try {
        // Create the draft message
        Draft draft = new Draft();
        draft.setMessage(message);
        draft = service.users().drafts().create("me", draft).execute();
        System.out.println("Draft id: " + draft.getId());
        System.out.println(draft.toPrettyString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

These lines are not resolvable in Intellij IDE.

```
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");

GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE);
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
```

The import is not resolved as i copy from internet.

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

By the way, I'm using JDK 18.

Questions:

1. Why the import are not resolved?
2. What is tokens directory? How to generate it?
3. What are the best method/facility send email with attachment?

Please help me. I really need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the email sending facility you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Think so there are some dependency are missing, this are `LocalServerReceiver` and `HttpCredentailsAdapter` and for the tokens directory once the auth is done on this place all the google API client library get stored. In the code directory is set as `tokens` this is mention to the root of the project directory.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
  <version>0.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How to generate the oauth token? Any documentation?

Comment: Yes, Think so this source will give the solution [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)